# PHP reg exp - where did DOI go?

Tags: php, regex

I just want to replace "doi:yyyy.yyyy" here, but $1 does not give me back that text. Why? ;-)

```
$zp_citation['citation'] = preg_replace('(doi:[^ <]*)',
                                    '<b>' . '$1' . " - where did doi go?" . '</b>',
                                    $zp_citation['citation'],
                                    1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing required [`regex delimiters`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php):

```
$zp_citation['citation'] = preg_replace('/(doi:[^ <]*)/',
                                        '<b>' . '$1' . " - where did doi go?" . '</b>',
                                        $zp_citation['citation'], 1);
```

Comment: more accurately, the `()` are being interpreted as the delimiters and thus not capturing

Comment: Yes that is correct @Eevee I should have mentioned it as well in my answer.

Comment: Aha, thanks. I did not think of that they could be delimiters too. It was some time since I edited PHP... ;-)